# Can I prevent users from sharing a document using App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I want to share a document with a user (1 document/user - 5500 users). I am using App Script and everything is going fine. But even if I restrict the document so that only the recipient of the file can see the document, he/she can still share it with other persons. I know, if I share it manually that I can check a box in advanced settings to prevent the person that I share a document with to share it or to copy, download and print it.

Is there a Google Apps Script equivalent to checking those boxes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control the permissions that a class of users has using Drive methods.

- [setShareableByEditors(false)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setShareableByEditors(Boolean)) can prevent editors from sharing a document.

Users are added to the collaborators list and granted specific permissions through these Drive Service methods:

- File.addViewer() or File.addViewers()
- File.addEditor() or File.addEditors()

You can check the permissions that a user has using:

- File.getAccess(user)